# How to detect collision amongst concentric circles

Tags: game-engine

In my shooting gallery game, i have a bulls-eye formed from concentric rings (each a separate object). It seems like for any collision bounds i use, the bounds for the outer rings cover the inner rings. Hence, when i hit the center ring, all rings sense a collision since the outer rings collision bounds overlap the center rings.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: try the "Triangle mesh" collision type.

Answer (score 1):

Add a single collision mesh for the entire board, then calculate the distance to the centre to determine which ring was hit.

Answer (score 0):

To get holes in a collision mesh, you need to use triangle mesh bounds.

Otherwise it will always assume the mesh is convex (which is faster to calculate).